# Testing output of Weka decision tree does not agree with the trained model's logic

Tags: classification, weka, decision-tree

I trained a decision tree model using the REPTree classifier in Weka. The model it produces is fairly simple:

```
Has Pool? = FALSE
|   Spike Count < 4.5
|   |   Early/Pump Demand < 0.94 : 0 (265/3) [128/1]
|   |   Early/Pump Demand >= 0.94
|   |   |   1-hour delta/day < 0.6 : 0 (26/0) [15/0]
|   |   |   1-hour delta/day >= 0.6
|   |   |   |   Daily Usage < 40.29 : 2 (17/0) [9/0]
|   |   |   |   Daily Usage >= 40.29 : 0 (7/3) [3/1]
|   Spike Count >= 4.5
|   |   Early/Pump Demand < 0.66 : 0 (10/0) [7/1]
|   |   Early/Pump Demand >= 0.66 : 2 (108/2) [55/2]
Has Pool? = TRUE : 3 (82/0) [41/0]
```

But when I re-evaluate this model on a separate testing set, none of the testing instances are classified into the '3' category, even though there are definitely instances where **Has Pool?** == True. The confusion matrix looks like this:

```
    a    b    c   <-- classified as
 2497   73    0 |    a = 0
    0    0    0 |    b = 2
    0    0    0 |    c = 3
```

There should be 85 in column c. If I manually apply the decision tree logic to the testing set in Excel, I get a different result in terms of how many wind up in each class. What's really stumping me is that if the first branch of the tree specifies that all instances where **Has Pool?** == True result in the instance being classified as '3', how can it be producing another result for those? Why does the output not agree with the tree's logic?

Comment: How did you evaluate your model: CV/train-test split/etc? Did perform the evaluation in the Weka Explorer or in your own code? Does the dedicated test set have the exact same structure as the training set (the Weka Explorer checks for that, your own code might not)?

Comment: @fracpete - The training and testing sets are entirely different. I used the "re-apply model to testing set" function in Weka Explorer for the evaluation. The structure for both sets is identical.